# Como utilizar Deserialización en JSON en C#

Tags: c#, json

Como puedo acceder a la información de "horario inicio" y "horario fin" para poder realizar una comparación con los días y horarios maquina.

Estaba utilizando newtonsoft pero no me funciona estaba intentando como esto

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm

```
[
    {
        "nom_sucursal": "Local1",
        "num_sucursal": 1,
        "num_cadena": 1,
        "status": 1,
        "cobertura": [
            {
                "lat": 1,
                "lng": 1
            },
            {
                "lat": 1,
                "lng": 1
            },
            {
                "lat": 1,
                "lng": 1
            },
            {
                "lat": 1,
                "lng": 1
            },
            {
                "lat": 1,
                "lng": 1
            }
        ],
        "horario_inicio": "{\"Lunes\": \"00:00\", \"Martes\": \"00:00\", \"Miercoles\": \"00:00\", \"Jueves\": \"00:00\", \"Viernes\": \"00:00\", \"Sabado\": \"00:00\",\"Domingo\": \"00:00\"}",
        "horario_fin": "{\"Lunes\": \"23:59\", \"Martes\": \"23:59\", \"Miercoles\": \"23:59\", \"Jueves\": \"23:59\", \"Viernes\": \"23:59\", \"Sabado\": \"23:59\",\"Domingo\": \"23:59\"}",
        "telefono": "",
        "direccion": "",
        "interfaz": 1,
        "email": "",
        "time_zone": "zona",
        "ubicacion_gps": ""
    }
]
```

Comment: hoy como 8 preguntas iguales en los ultimos 6 meses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para esto únicamente necesitamos lo siguiente.

Creamos las clases del json mediante la siguiente herramienta [json2charp](https://json2csharp.com/)

```
 public class Cobertura
    {
        public double lat { get; set; }
        public double lng { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public string nom_sucursal { get; set; }
        public int num_sucursal { get; set; }
        public int num_cadena { get; set; }
        public int status { get; set; }
        public List<Cobertura> cobertura { get; set; }
        public string horario_inicio { get; set; }
        public string horario_fin { get; set; }
        public string telefono { get; set; }
        public string direccion { get; set; }
        public int interfaz { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public string time_zone { get; set; }
        public string ubicacion_gps { get; set; }
    }
```

Y utilizamos Newtonsoft

```
string respuestaH = @"path.json";

List<Root> horariosInicio = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(respuestaH);
```

Y aqui ya podemos acceder a los datos de horario_inicio

```
Root h1 = horariosInicio[0]; 
Console.WriteLine(h1.horario_inicio);
```